# Custom view object using up full height of screen even when layout_height is set to wrap_content

Tags: android, view, android-widget

I created an object that extends `android.view.View`, overriding `draw()` and have it displaying on the screen. To put you in the picture, it is a display of digits to represent a game score. It's displaying correctly horizontally, however, it is taking up the full height of the screen - pushing all other elements off the screen.

I've put `layout_height="wrap_content"` in the xml, but it has no effect.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've figured it out...

I was supposed to override onDraw() but that wasn't what caused the problem.

The main thing was, I needed to override onMeasure() like this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    setMeasuredDimension(DIGIT_WIDTH * getNumberOfDigits(), DIGIT_HEIGHT);
}
```

`DIGIT_WIDTH` and `DIGIT_HEIGHT` are constants set to the dimensions of each digit image I used. `getNumberOfDigits()` is just a getter for a custom property set from the xml attributes.

Hope that helps anyone else coming across this.