# Why my Layout is going on Full screen when set to wrap_content

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

My layout, is going on full screen, 
although it is set to wrap_content.
I was reading this might be because somewhere in the layout there is align parent button , but in my layout i don't do relative to parent but

Why is it still on full screen ?

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3edfbc"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3edfbc" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:text="Initlizing Wifi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/barcodeScanning_spinkit"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.Wave"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        app:SpinKit_Color="#ffffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @LubomirBabev `When you set your View to wrap_content, it get his parent size` **NO**. It gets its contents total size.

Comment: In preview the xml design looks like that. If you install it on device or emulator. It will be take wrap_content as a width/height.

Comment: @ Bob Malooga  ?  except in my case it still does it on full screen

Comment: it's something to do with the view i guess, just don't know why it screw all the other layout

Answer (score 0):

try this it will work

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#3edfbc"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<View
    android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_view"
    android:background="#3edfbc" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Initlizing Wifi"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
<com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/barcodeScanning_spinkit"
    style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.Wave"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:SpinKit_Color="#ffffff" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you cannot remove the layout_height, and layout_width from the View component... it errors it out, every componenet has to have a width and a hight

Comment: ok based on the view you could specify  height value otherwise use this android:layout_height="0dp".

Comment: making, android:layout_height="0dp just removes the view completely, and scpecigying a spacific value is a bad way to program, becouse it will look diffrent at any phone, and when later i'll change the text of the layout, it will change the dialog size, and then the size i gave wouldn't matter...

Comment: ok Cool use android dimension folder based on the different android device just gives the value.

Comment: again i need the size to be dynamic becouse the dialog changes throught the app depence on what i put inside of it

Answer (score 0):

Change your View inside relative layout to some other view like textView or imageView.

Use below code to get required design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#3edfbc"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#3edfbc" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:text="Initlizing Wifi"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />

<com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView 
    android:id="@+id/barcodeScanning_spinkit"
    style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.Wave"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:SpinKit_Color="#ffffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but then i wouldn't have the view there as a background color that i want to catch and change everytime, the idea of it all is that i'll be able to change the dialog backgorund color programaticaly

Comment: You can change textView color also na. If that view is only to change background color purpose, then you can change it to TextView or ImageView. This wont be an issue.

Comment: This is true. I dont know why using View will max out the height even if it's wrap_content. Setting it to TextView solves it.

Answer (score -1):

1) Remove `com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView` view
2) remove `orientation` from relative layout.

Comment: if i remove the com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView, it's not my deisgred layout anymore, removing orientation doesn't do anything

Comment: Look like problem with view. try to give a static size to view.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422806/custom-view-object-using-up-full-height-of-screen-even-when-layout-height-is-set